# Switch to iframe in Nightwatch 2.2.2

Tags: iframe, nightwatch.js

Did anybody manage to figure out how to switch to an iframe in the latest Nightwatch 2.2.2?

For example, browser.frame(1) => seems deprecated.
The ELEMENT doesn't exist anymore in version 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed with Nightwatch v2.3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).